String representation of GVariant
Is there a function to parse a generic glib GVariant pointer into a const char*?
Such as the way it's done in DBus?
signal time=1717768489.237441 sender=:1.22 -> destination=(null destination) serial=17 path=/org/bluez/hci0; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=PropertiesChanged

string "org.bluez.Adapter1"
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "Powered"
         variant             boolean false
      )
      dict entry(
         string "Discovering"
         variant             boolean false
      )
   ]
   array [
   ]


Side note you don't want a const char* you want a std::string. And how much effort have you put into finding a library/documentation>

I finally found it! Obviously, I'd much rather prefer an std::string than const char*, but since this library is very C-stylish I had no such hope. The somewhat cumbersome API can be hidden in a helper function:
std::string print_variant(GVariant* v) {
  auto* res = g_variant_print_string(v, nullptr, true);
  if (nullptr == res->str) {
    return "NULL";
  }
  std::string retval(res->str, res->len);
  g_string_free(res, true);
  return retval;
}


Have you looked into whether glibmm has an equivalent? I believe those are the C++ style GLib bindings.

GString is actually a string builder API but is somewhat misnamed. g_variant_print is less cumbersome because you don't have to mess around with the string builder object, it'll just return a newly allocated 0-terminated char*:
std::string print_variant(GVariant *v) {
  g_autofree char* res = g_variant_print(v, true);
  return {res};
}

